# Send GPS (NMEA) to a real phone via DDMS?

Tags: android, gps, ddms

I was having issues with the DDMS's ability to send GPS data to my emulator (i needed speed, accuracy, heading, etc all to change but couldn't get that to work with DDMS). Anyhow, I wrote a quick script to connect to the debug port and send nmea sentences following a track from a gpx file (nmea sentences modelled off an nexus s) but added the extra data i needed. I know there are other gps emulators out there, but for various reasons I ended up writing my own.

The question I have is, is there a way to do this to a real phone? I've trawled through the ddms info i can find and cant find much of use?

I've seen one emulator that can do this via bluetooth, but had trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you can send GPS data to a phone, which must have `USB debugging` and `Mock locations` allowed in settings.

Comment: afaik, the only thing that allows you to do is to send mock locations via the ddms component in adt?

which isnt really what i'm after cause unless its changed recently its incapable of sending speed/accuracy/etc. it only sends a sequence of points to the phone?

unless theres a way of sending nmea sentences via ddms im not aware of?

Comment: When I plug in my phone, a device "LGE Android Platform USB GPS NMEA Port" appears hm

Comment: I think you'll probably find that that is actually your real gps on your phone presenting itself as a usb-to-serial device. i.e. if you cat /dev/ttyUSB0 (or whatever it comes up as) you might find your gps is pumping out nmea sentences on that port... none of my phones do this though (htc desire, sgs2 and nexus s), though if im correct you'll find that appear even if mock locations is off. Though if the LG does do allow you to push nmes sentences into the phone, that would be nice!